# How do I fire a click function with React and Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React and TypeScript.

I want to make a simple function that just fires a `console.log();` I've gone through a few tutorials but don't really understand.

I've created an interface as such as per the tutorial:

```
interface ClickHandlerProps {
  onClick; (event: React.SyntheticEvent<Event>, buttonType: string) => void
}
```

And in the return function I have:

```
<Button
  onClick={(e) => props.onClick(e, "button1")}
>
```

But the tutorial kind of ends there. I don't really know how to just fire a console.log().

I know it's a bit vague, but could anyone help me out and point me in the right direction?

Full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

interface ClickHandlerProps {
  onClick; (event: React.SyntheticEvent<Event>, buttonType: string) => void
}

const ActionButtons = ({ onClick }: EventHandlerProps) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Button onClick={(e) => props.onClick(e, "button1")} >
            Button 1
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Button onClick={(e) => props.onClick(e, "button2")} >
            Button 2
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default ActionButtons;
```

On index.tsx

```
import ActionButtons from './ActionButtons';
export default ActionButtons;
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo here: you must use the colon to separate the property name from its type.

```
interface ClickHandlerProps {
  onClick: (event: React.SyntheticEvent<Event>, buttonType: string) => void
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get a `props is not defined` message though. Would you know what that means?

Comment: because you are using `props` in the event handlers, whereas you actually do not need it. Change it to: `onClick={(e) => onClick(e, "button1")}`

Comment: Thanks I did remove that but then it jsut doesn't recognise `onClick`: `onClick is not a function`

Comment: that depends on how your `ActionButtons` is called. You should edit the post and add that piece of code.

Comment: Thanks - have added above

Comment: that is a simple declaration, which redirects to another module. It's useless. You probably have the ActionButtons somewhere else, like in the first snippet of the other answer.

Comment: Oh sorry - yeah I just  have `return <ActionButtons />;`

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use your `ActionButtons` component like this:

```js
import React, {SyntheticEvent} from 'react';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const clickHandler = (evt: SyntheticEvent<Event>, btnType: string) => {
    console.log(`Button clicked: ${btnType}`
  };

  return <ActionButtons onClick={clickHandler}></ActionButtons>
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Notice you're passing `clickHandler` function to `onClick` input, so any click inside `ActionButtons` will call `clickHandler`.

BTW, there seem to be some errors on the example `ActionButtons` component:

```js
const ActionButtons = ({ onClick }: EventHandlerProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Button onClick={(e) => onClick(e, "button1")} >
            Button 1
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Button onClick={(e) => onClick(e, "button2")} >
            Button 2
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default ActionButtons;
```